# `kate` tab does not have any color

Tags: 14.04, text-editor, kate

`kate` tab plugin:
http://kate-editor.org/2011/04/25/kates-tab-bar-plugins/

1) On Ubuntu 14.04, does anyone know why the tab color cannot be changed? (I can see the option `Highlight Tab` is available, but there is no effect at all when selecting a specific color for the tab).

2) Is there any shortcut to quickly switch between tabs?

Comment: There are shortcuts, Alt+Left, Alt+Right.

Comment: of course. When I click right button, it does not show any context menu.

Comment: In my case, it does show the context menu, but it doesn't have any effect on color. Thanks for the shortcuts.

Comment: Which version of Kate are you using?
I'm also running Kate on 14.04, but In my system the color are working.
Please add the `kate --version` to the question.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04,  Kate: 3.14.13, Qt: 4.8.6, and KDE 4.14.13

Comment: I'm using default kate version of 14.04 (install via `sudo apt-get install kate`).  About page show: `Kate Version 3.13.3, Using KDE Development Platform 4.13.3`

Comment: Btw, how did you install `kate` in your 14.04 system?